# Angular Component won't change after changes happened on services

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an assignment in angular but everytime i change an element value it wont change on the browser but i know it was already changed because of the console log.
The assignment is like to toggle an the status of a member from active to inactive vice versa. it was changed but the browser keep showing the same thing.

inactive and active member have their own component.

users.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {
  Users = [
    {name: 'Anna', active: true},
    {name: 'Joey', active: false},
    {name: 'Bords', active: true},
    {name: 'Rhea', active: false},
    {name: 'Glenn', active: true}
  ]

  constructor() { }

  changeStatus(id: number){
    console.log(this.Users[id])
    this.Users[id].active = !this.Users[id].active
    console.log(this.Users[id])
  }
}
```

Active-user component

TS file

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from '../users.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-active-users',
  templateUrl: './active-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./active-users.component.css']
})
export class ActiveUsersComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() ActiveUsers = [];

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.usersService.Users.forEach((value, index) => {
      if(value.active){
        this.ActiveUsers.push({id: index, name: value.name})
      }
    })
  }

  changeStatus(id: number) {
    this.usersService.changeStatus(id);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<h3>Active Users</h3>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li
    class="list-group-item"
    *ngFor="let user of ActiveUsers">
    {{ user.name }} | <a href="#" (click)="changeStatus(user.id)">Set to Active</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

InActive Component

TS file

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from '../users.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inactive-users',
  templateUrl: './inactive-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inactive-users.component.css']
})
export class InactiveUsersComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() inActiveUsers = [];
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.usersService.Users.forEach((value, index) => {
      if(!value.active){
        this.inActiveUsers.push({id: index, name: value.name})
      }
    })
  }

  changeStatus(id: number) {
    this.usersService.changeStatus(id);
  }
}
```

HTML file

```
<h3>Inactive Users</h3>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li
    class="list-group-item"
    *ngFor="let user of inActiveUsers">
    {{ user.name }} | <a href="#" (click)="changeStatus(user.id)">Set to Active</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

App Component

TS file

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [UsersService],
})
export class AppComponent{
  
}
```

HTML file

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <app-active-users></app-active-users>
      <app-inactive-users></app-inactive-users>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There’s nothing reactive about your code. ActiveUsers is set once, changeStatus changes the Users in service but this has no connection to the components. You need to use Subjects and observables.

Comment: Oh okay. I guess im not on that part yet cause honestly this is an assignment from an online course and he used 2 arrays for inactive and active users and just splice them. I wanted to use online 1 array and it seems i need to progress more on the course. Sorry bout that. I just want to improvise i guess.

Comment: nothing to apologise for, if I wasn’t on mobile I’d have posted a demo. The angular tutorial is a nice place to read up on this methodology https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#observable-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it reactive, you can do something like this:

1. Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from ‘rxjs’;


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {
  Users = new BehaviorSubject([
    {name: 'Anna', active: true},
    {name: 'Joey', active: false},
    {name: 'Bords', active: true},
    {name: 'Rhea', active: false},
    {name: 'Glenn', active: true}
  ]);

  constructor() { }

  changeStatus(id: number){
    const users = this.Users.getValue();
    users[id].active = !users[id].active;
    this.Users.next(users);
  }
}
```

2. inactive.component.ts ( ngOnInit code )

```
this.usersService.Users.subscribe(users => {
    users.forEach((value, index) => {
         if(!value.active) { 
            this.inActiveUsers.push({id: index, name: value.name})
         }
    });
})
```

3. active.component.ts

```
this.usersService.Users.subscribe(users => {
    users.forEach((value, index) => {
         if(value.active) { 
            this.ActiveUsers.push({id: index, name: value.name})
         }
    });
})
```